# Type mismatch: 'CInt' - VBScript error in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, vbscript, type-mismatch

I have an input form where I have a hidden field that keeps a number. I'm sure it can only be a number (from -1 to ...) because I set the value with javascript. By default it's 0 and I only do value++ or value--.
The only code I have is this:

> var counter = 0;
>
> or
>
> counter++
>
> or
>
> counter--
>
> or
>
> (to set the value in the hidden field) document.getElementById('counterHidden').value = counter;

Now after the submit I get an error in Firefox (in IE it is working)

The error is:

> "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch: 'CInt' "

This is at the line where I want to convert the input value to an int:

> counterValue = CInt(Request.Form("counterHidden"))

If I set an alert before I submit the form I see -1 or 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or ...

So why do I still have the error in firefox?

Comment: Since when does Firefox support client-side VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the parameter to CInt cannot be converted to Integer since it is not an integer itself. It looks, you are trying to call CInt when Request.Form("counterHidden") does not possess an integer convertible value probably some null value or uninitialized value. Print the value of Request.Form("counterHidden") prior to calling CInt and check what it possess.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the Integer data type only works for numbers up to ~32000.  If your counter is getting higher than that, it will return a type mismatch also.  Try changing your CInt to CLng.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: A number >32767 would raise an overflow error (0x800a0006), not a type mismatch.